# Test reviews within the past 30 days?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

I recently had this as one of the 'test reviews':

[image]

As you can see, this was asked on the *9th June*. It was last active *23* days ago.

I clearly remembered seeing this question recently (in fact, I upvoted this one) so I knew that this was a 'test'. I am also *pretty sure* that this type of thing has happened before (only once before), if not on SU.

So my question is: *What is the point of having the 'review tests' if it is **so** obvious that it is a test*?

Shouldn't the tests be ***at least*** 2 months old? **Or** older than your 'member for' date? (Although I think some people have been on this site since it was established, but I doubt they will remember questions that far back).

**Also:**

When you click the section to review, if it says something like `1` (or a small number, which is *memorable*) and you review one post, click 'No action', 'Skip', or 'I'm done', and another post comes up, it is, again, *pretty obvious* that these are just tests.

This is what I mean by 'section to review':

[image]

Comment: Well, bear in mind that (unless you’re reviewing at the speed of light) a new item could have been added to the queue while you were reviewing the first one.

Comment: @Scott Yes, that's entirely possible although that's never happened for me (but I've only been a user for about 3 months...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're thinking about when the question was asked, then you're already thinking about that post more than the typical review robot we're trying to catch does.

The post is not an obvious audit if you just mash the "No action needed" button.

But I agree that the small number of review items at any given time will make people realize that audits are coming. It's usually the case for me when I review suggested edits.