# Suggested Edit 'This item is not reviewable'

Tags: support, review, review-audits

I was in the Suggested Edits Review Queue, completed one review and clicked 'Next'. It took a bit of time to get to the next one and this is what it was:

[image]

This is obviously supposed to be an audit (I know because I had already completed the amount of reviews it said on the [Review](https://superuser.com/review) page, as I also talked about [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8183/test-reviews-within-the-past-30-days) (last section of the question)).

Is this a bug? Or did something weird happen at that moment in time that messed it up for me?

This was the item: https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/259796

Comment: Can you link to the review task? It's kinda useless like this for us to try to figure out what happened, as is

Comment: @CanadianLuke Sorry, I forgot to! Edited it!

Comment: @Oded So I guess it's not a bug? Just happened to me?

Comment: @ṧнʊß - yes. Some items are placed in the review queue, but later (due to voted and other changes to their status), are no longer eligible for review. It can happen that you hit on such an item, though it is rare.

Comment: @Oded OK, thanks!